# Can "will have you doing a double take" be rewritten as "will make you do a double take"?

Tags: causatives

> These adult film stars will have you doing a double take when you see them without any makeup on.

Source: http://www.lolwot.com/10-adult-film-celebs-without-makeup/

I would like to ask whether there is possible to rewrite this sentence without a change of the meaning in this way:

> These adult film stars will make you do a double take when you see them without any makeup on.

Comment: Yes. There is no change in meaning.

Comment: And what about "These adult film stars will have you do a double take when you see them without any makeup on". Does ing form indicate the process of duration of the activity?

Comment: @bart-leby, I can't quite put my finger on it, but that's kinda creepy. maybe **have you do** sounds a bit too... biblical... for this context? https://www.google.com.eg/#q=%22have+you+do%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=10

Comment: Not in this context. A double take happens quickly. We'd probably need to use *long* to describe one of any real duration. Like maybe a photographer to a model. *Let's do a sort of long double take.* Some unusual situation.

Comment: The phrase "do a double take" in your sentence "Let's do a sort of long double take" in the hypotetical situation with a model and a photographer is used in the literal meaning?

Comment: Yes, but it would be staged or acted. E.g., *Show me what a double take looks like. Now do a long one, in slow motion.*

Comment: @bart-leby In case you don't know exactly what a _double take_ is, a good demonstration is [**here.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ou1al8mlYU)

Comment: He had us explaining it all to him. He made us explain it all to him, [There is possible, is not idiomatic. You mean: whether it is possible]

Answer (score 1):

The question, as asked, gets at the concept of "passive" vs. "active" influence. "Have you doing" describes the situation where the action encourages you (induces you) to do a double take. If we were to rewrite the sentence as "make you do", we are describing the situation as more forceful. Thus the meaning IS changed by the rewrite. The original is more pleasant to the reader. You'll be encouraged to do a double take. The changed sentence is more in the direction of "you WILL do a double take whether you wish to or not."

Note the comments to the original question state the change of wording does not change the meaning. The two versions ARE the same meaning on the literal level. But on the emotional level, I see them as different.

Comment: I agree with the explanation. Well done.